# How to detect if user dismisses iAd's interstitial ad

Tags: ios, swift, iad, dismiss, interstitial

I'm implementing iAd in my app.

Whenever the users finished a game, I want to show an interstitial ad. as soon as the user dismissed this interstitial ad, I also want to hide the viewcontroller that showed the game, taking the user back to my main menu.

I tried:

```
func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        NSLog("hidden")
    }
```

but this doesn't get triggered if I dismiss the ad.

Is there any way, if necessary custom implemented, how I can trigger a method when the user dismisses my ad?

Comment: I just found the same problem in iOS 9. In the developer mode, only when you play the ad and then dismiss it, the "Unload" delegate function will be triggered. If you directly dismiss the ad, this delegate function will not be called.